# How to get zipCode from object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this:

```
[Object]
  0:Object
    zipCode:"1232"
```

Now what i want is to get zipCode from object i tried with this:

`Object[0].zipCode` but i get message that 0 is undefined

Update:

```
 this.restService.getByParam("findAddress", customerId)
                    .subscribe(results =>   {
                    this.address = results.payload;
                });
```

And then i get that object and now i want to do something like this:

```
console.log(this.address[0].zipCode
```

Comment: Try `Object[0]?.zipCode` (if this is async, like http-request)

Comment: im getting error in ts file ':' expected.

Comment: Right, yeah I realized that this might not be code in template, but in component, so disregard the above comment :)

Comment: where do you try and access this data? Is this a http request? could you post that piece of code?

Comment: yes thats it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = { 0 : {'zipCode':"1232"} }

for(var key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key].zipCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here u go :

```
var foo = { 0 : {'zipCode':"1232"} }

for(var key in foo) {
var value = foo[key];
}

console.log(value); // this give you 'zipCode':"1232"
console.log(value['zipCode']); // this give you "1232"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/9d58ebuy/